# Force a C compiler to produce integer narrowing warning

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

Let's consider the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(unsigned char c) {
   printf("0x%x\n", c);
}

int main() {
   int val = 0x11223344;
   func(val);
}
```

To my best knowledge, there is **no way** I can force `gcc` nor `clang`, to show a warning on the statement `func(val)` about the narrowing `int` -> `unsigned char` that will happen there. Not even by compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. The question targets mainly `C` code, but it is worth including the `C++` world in the discussion as well (see the note below).

### C++ Note

I'm well aware that in `C++` exists a kind-of workaround using the *uniform initialization syntax*:

```
func({val});
```

But that does **not** solve my problem because:

- for preexisting code, it requires changes
- for new code, it would require using `{}` everywhere

### Question 1

Is there any arcane option to achieve that when compiling `C` or `C++` code? I'm fine also with a non-standard solution as long as it works with `gcc` or `clang` and it does **not** require changing the code. **Note:** I'm not looking for tricky `C++` solutions using custom integer types with or without macros that wrap primitive types. I'm looking for something like a command-line option or a `pragma`. Again, the question is mostly for `C` code, but it's worth exploring any `C++` solutions too.

### Question 2 (fall-back)

If the reality turns out to be that (as suspected) no such solution exists, I'd be super-curious to understand why. I can't believe that such an option was just never considered to be implemented. There should be a list of reasonable arguments against it, that I just can't think of. But the thing is that the option could be simply non-standard like `-fwrapv` and people could use it only where it is really needed.

Comment: Are there any required warnings in the specifications for any version of C/C++? I thought that was up to the vender implementation, and as such would be pretty specific to a language and compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is `-Wconversion` what you're looking for?

You can see the behavior [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion), with a lot of cases.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for! `gcc` produces the following warning:
`warning: conversion to ‘unsigned char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]`

Comment: I was waiting stackoverflow to allow me to do that (there's a 5-min minimum time). Thanks so much!!

Comment: @vvaltchev Happy to help. You would think `-Wall` would be more inclusive. By the way, on `clang`, you can use `-Weverything`.

Comment: Thanks! `-Weverything` seems great. Unfortunately, it does not exist on `clang` 6 :-(

Comment: You _can_ use `-Weverything`, but you shouldn't. https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/12/06/dont-use-weverything/. GCC doesn't have this flag precisely because it's a bad idea. You'll end up with bogus warnings like like https://stackoverflow.com/q/64471930/148195 when you upgrade your compiler.

Comment: @mk12 Cool, nice read, thank you for sharing.